# MySQL query select all fields with same value

Tags: mysql, select, having

be I'm looking for help in writing a MySQL query.

Each row has a minimum of two rows with the same conversation_id. I want to select those that that have "delete" in the recipient_state field in all rows with the same conversation_id.

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM xf_conversation_recipient
GROUP BY recipient_state HAVING (delete in all fields)
```

The following conversation_id would be selected

```
conversation_id recipient_state
1               delete
1               delete
```

The following conversation_id would NOT be selected

```
conversation_id recipient_state
1               delete
1               active
```

Comment: `Each row has a minimum of two rows` you need to correct this

Comment: i thin kyour question may be more clear if you provide some sample data

Comment: I added two examples. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(DISTINCT recipient_state) AS nb, recipient_state
FROM xf_conversation_recipient
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING nb=1 AND recipient_state='delete'
```

The query groups by conversation_id, keeps only records having 1 distinct recipient_state and recipient_state is equal to 'delete'.

Comment: That works perfect. Thank you, Jocelyn. I really appreciate you sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can come up with is a self-left-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.conversation_id
FROM xf_conversation_recipient AS r1
LEFT JOIN xf_conversation_recipient AS r2 ON r2.conversation_id = r1.conversation_id AND r2.recipient_state != 'delete'
WHERE r1.recipient_state = 'delete' AND r2.conversation_id IS NULL
```

Basically, grab all rows where there are no matching rows that don't have "delete" as the state.

Comment: Very close to my thoughts. However, I would do DISTINCT conversation ID, and pre-qualify that you want conversations that have at least 1 "Delete" entry (via WHERE r1.recipient_state = 'delete') clause.  Why query 10k entries if only 200 of them have a 'delete' status.  Otherwise, I would have just queried the entire file with counts(*) vs count( 'deleted' status ) entries and kept only if counts were the same.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian. I tried your query but got no results. I don't understand the r1 and r2 values you added. Normally when use a join I add the table name before the field.

Comment: Hello, Drapp. Would you be so kind as to provide an example. Thank you.

Comment: @DRapp - good points, edited to include those changes. @Andy, the r1 and r2 are table aliases; I've added explicit `AS` keywords to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Given a table `xf_conversation_recipient` that looks like this:

```
+----------------+----------------+
|conversation_id |recipient_state |
+----------------+----------------+
|1               |delete          |
|1               |delete          |
|2               |active          |
|2               |delete          |
|3               |delete          |
|3               |delete          |
|4               |active          |
|4               |delete          |
|5               |active          |
|5               |active          |
|6               |delete          |
|6               |delete          |
+----------------+----------------+
```

The following query returns the IDs of all conversations matching your criteria

```
SELECT 
    conversation_id AS selectedId, 
    count(*) AS count    
FROM xf_conversation_recipient   
WHERE recipient_state = "delete" 
GROUP BY conversation_id 
HAVING count>1
```

Returns:

```
+-----------+------+
|selectedId |count |
+-----------+------+
|1          |2     |
|3          |2     |
|6          |2     |
+-----------+------+
```

Note, depending on your application, you may want to stop here.

---

Nesting this query, we can extract only the `selectedId` column, and nesting it again we can use that as an `IN` condition on a query, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM xf_conversation_recipient 
WHERE xf_conversation_recipient.conversation_id IN (
    SELECT t1.selectedId FROM (
        SELECT 
            conversation_id AS selectedId, 
            count(*) AS count
        FROM xf_conversation_recipient
        WHERE recipient_state = "delete"
        GROUP BY conversation_id
        HAVING count>1
    ) t1  
)
```

Which returns:

```
+----------------+----------------+
|conversation_id |recipient_state |
+----------------+----------------+
|1               |delete          |
|1               |delete          |
|3               |delete          |
|3               |delete          |
|6               |delete          |
|6               |delete          |
+----------------+----------------+
```